Emmet's doc snippet not adding "http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'" meta tag. Why?
I've been trying Emmet boiler plate in vs code on html files and when i see tutorials online emmet have 3 meta tags when they use but when i use Emmet in vs code on html there are only 2 meta tags, one meta tag is missing as shown in screenshots below

Screenshot of my Emmet boiler plate
Screenshot of a tutorial online having 3 meta tags in Emmet boiler plate
This Meta tag is missing from my boiler plate

I tried reinstalling whole vs code the problem still exist. I am expecting my Emmet boiler plate for html in vs code to have all 3 Meta tags (currently only 2 out of 3 meta tags in there).

please convert your images of code into code blocks (text- not images)

VS Code's builtin Emmet extension gets its builtin snippets from Emmet itself. See src/snippets/html.json. If you go through the history of that file, you'll find commit 2b037b5, with the message "remove meta[http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'] from "doc" snippet (#694)". If you click into that PR, you'll see this explanation by Doc Oliver:

IE 11 has been EOL for quite some time now. This change removes the obsolete meta[http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'] from the HTML "doc" snippet.

